# Can i transfer money via Indian bank atm to citibank account?

Tags: india, atm, transfer

I have a Bank Account with Indian Bank.
Is it possible for me to transfer money from my Indian bank account via atm to Citibank Account?

If Yes what the steps to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few Bank in India allow Funds Transfer via ATM. One has to first register the beneficiary account and wait for 24 hrs before transacting.

However it looks like "Indian Bank" currently does not offer this service. You can call up Indian Bank and ask if they provide this service.

Alternativly use the Internet Banking to transfer funds to CitiBank or any other Bank in India.

Answer (score 1):

In India, transferring to other banks is available mostly on Internet banking. Some banks are offering Transferring option within the bank in ATMs. You need to visit the bank branch to register and activate this Transfer option for intra-bank accounts.